# Virtual PC XP mode cannot start: "library not registered"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

When I try and start Windows Virtual PC --> XP Mode I get the error "cannot start windows virtual pc host process" ... "library not registered"

Can't work out why.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/abec3e39-ec2d-468a-8090-db7df19ced26